# How to change model in Tensorflow camera example?

Tags: ios, xcode, camera, computer-vision, tensorflow

In the tensorflow camera example, tensorflow has provided a graph file called **tensorflow_inception_graph.pb** but I tried to replace it with my own .pb graph file that I trained using tensorflow using this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QfNvhPx5Px8 I also replaced the txt file, but there was still a problem.

When I copied it in, no text/numbers showed up when I ran it, but it ran perfectly ok. Do you guys know how I can fix it?